# SWFUpload in FireFox

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, swfupload

I'm using SWFUpload in my MVC3 program.It works well in IE and Chrome.But my files cannot be uploaded in FireFox.It doesn't even go into the Upload Action.
In my program,users should log in first.And when I use SWFUpload in a test program which users do not have to log in, it also works well.
Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem ?
This is my code:

```
Js:
   swfupload1 = new SWFUpload({
        upload_url: '@Url.Action("Upload")',
        post_params: { "name": "value" },

        file_size_limit: "200000000",
        file_types: "*.jpg;*.gif;*.png;*.jpeg",
        file_types_description: "",
        file_upload_limit: "1",
        file_queue_limit: "1",

        file_queue_error_handler: fileQueueError,
        file_dialog_complete_handler: fileDialogComplete,
        file_queued_handler: fileQueued,
        upload_progress_handler: uploadProgress,
        upload_error_handler: uploadError,
        upload_success_handler: uploadSuccess, 
        upload_complete_handler: uploadComplete,
        upload_start_handler: uploadStart,

        button_image_url:'@Url.Content("~/Swfupload/images/XPButtonNoText2_160x22.png")', 
        button_placeholder_id: "spanButtonPlaceholder1", 
        button_width: 42,
        button_height: 22,
        button_text: '<span class="buttonCss">选择</span>', 
        button_text_style: ".buttonCss { font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14pt; } .buttonSmall { font-size: 10pt; }", 
        button_text_top_padding: 1,
        button_text_left_padding: 5,
        button_cursor: SWFUpload.CURSOR.HAND,
        button_action: SWFUpload.BUTTON_ACTION.SELECT_FILE, 

        flash_url: '@Url.Content("~/Swfupload/swfupload.swf")',
        custom_settings: { upload_target: "divFileProgressContainer1" },

        debug: false
    });
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase filedata)
    {
        if (null != filedata)
        {
           filedata.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/File/Coverurl"+fileData.FileName));
        }
        return Json("");
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any code checking login status or not.

Comment: No,It does't check.I just don't konw what the problem is.Does it matter session?

Comment: It's the requirement you stated: `In my program,users should log in first.`

Comment: I just means in a test program which users do not have to login,it works well.But in my program which users should login first, it doesn't work.I used the same codes in these two programs.

Comment: understand. Any error in Firefox/Firebug's console log ? Any minor error in JS will make codes stopped completely.

Comment: I find the resolution here :http://www.cnblogs.com/rupeng/archive/2012/01/30/2332427.html.

Comment: maybe you can close the question (to avoid this question closing as "too localized") / answer your question yourself (to earn points). Try to help people.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest interested parties have a look at a solution here:http://www.cnblogs.com/rupeng/archive/2012/01/30/2332427.html.